# Create a list of sequent year month in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, datetime, relativedelta

I try to create a list of `year-month` from `2020-06` (last month from today) to `2021-05` using the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
need_months = list(range(-1, 12))
print([(datetime.today()+ relativedelta(months=i if i < 0 else i - 1)).strftime('%Y-%m') for i in need_months])
```

Out:

```
['2020-06', '2020-06', '2020-07', '2020-08', '2020-09', '2020-10', '2020-11', '2020-12', '2021-01', '2021-02', '2021-03', '2021-04', '2021-05']
```

But as you may noticed, there are two `2020-06` in the list.

How could I do it correctly?

The expected result:

```
['2020-06', '2020-07', '2020-08', '2020-09', '2020-10', '2020-11', '2020-12', '2021-01', '2021-02', '2021-03', '2021-04', '2021-05']
```

Comment: Why not just use `need_months = list(range(12))`? or simpler (and better) `[... for i in range(12)`]?

Comment: It works, if I want it starts from `2020-05`?

Comment: you tagged this with pandas. `pandas.date_range` handles this easily without any loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible use [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html) with convert today to month period by [`Timestamp.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_period.html), for previous month subtract `1` and add 12 periods parameter:

```
now = pd.Timestamp.now().to_period('m')
L = pd.period_range(now-1, freq='M', periods=12).strftime('%Y-%m').tolist()
print (L)
['2020-06', '2020-07', '2020-08', '2020-09', '2020-10', '2020-11', 
 '2020-12', '2021-01', '2021-02', '2021-03', '2021-04', '2021-05']
```

Comment: I think there is error: `strftime('%Y-%M')`, `M` should be `m`?

Comment: In fact, I'm trying to avoid to use a definitive date value `2021-05`, that's why I create a list. In stead, I hope the date list ends in the next `12` months starting from `2020-06`.

Comment: @ahbon - Just it is simplier if use 12 periods parameter, edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
need_months = list(range(-1, 12))
```

to

```
need_months = list(range(0, 12))
print([(datetime.today()+ relativedelta(months=i if i < 0 else i - 1)).strftime('%Y-%m') for i in need_months])
```

Output:-

```
'2020-06', '2020-07', '2020-08', '2020-09', '2020-10', '2020-11', '2020-12', '2021-01', '2021-02', '2021-03', '2021-04', '2021-05']
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, if I want it starts from `2020-05`?

Comment: @ahbon, That solution is posted by Chris.

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of `if`-`else` in `relativedata` works as expected:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
need_months = list(range(-1, 12))
print([(datetime.today()+ 
        relativedelta(months=i-1)).strftime('%Y-%m') 
       for i in need_months])
```

Output:

```
['2020-05', '2020-06', '2020-07', '2020-08', '2020-09', '2020-10', '2020-11', '2020-12', '2021-01', '2021-02', '2021-03', '2021-04', '2021-05']
```